# Read parameters in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

How to pass parameters to a batch script that has been defined in a separate file  such as a configuration file.

I am a newbie with batch scripting and trying to learn . Any help appreciated

Comment: Open a command prompt window and type: `call /?`

Comment: [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) great reference site - especially for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

In batch, parameters are referenced as `%1` for the first to `%9` for the ninth.
`%0` references the name of the running batchfile.
`%*` references "all parameters"

There are some modifiers to get just the part you want. See [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and `call /?`

To quickly show the concept:

Try this command line with below batchfile:

```
test.bat "C:\my folder\subfolder\test.txt" hello world
```

batchfile:

```
@echo off
echo this file: %0
echo this full qualified file name: %~f0
echo drive for this file: %~d0
echo path for this file: %~p0
echo this filename: %~n0
echo this file's extension: %~x0

echo param1: %1
echo full qualified file name: %~f1
echo drive: %~d1
echo path: %~p1
echo filename: %~n1
echo extension: %~x1

echo param 2: %2
echo param 3: %3

echo all parameters: %*
```